# Loading all files in jQuery ajax before success function PHP jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script like this.

The jQuery ajax loads all my files with no issues.
The ajax_load_books.php file have lot of css and js(inline edit, sliders etc.)   files in it.

**The problem is:**

How to load all the files before the success function so that the user can see the `loader_div` message untill all the files are loaded.
In other words - Load all the js/css files and proceed with the success function. 
Even I have checked with `.load()` function. Could someone redefine the below code .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".form-control").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id=' + id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_load_books.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#loader_div").show();
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#loader_div").hide();
                    $("#txtHint").html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks,

Kimz

Comment: So what is happening currently?

Comment: everything is loading immediately but the js and css are applied after few seconds after the page is loaded.

Comment: There shouldn't be a heavy lag unless you have a lot of files to load which I guess you do, in that case you can use a function like [jQuery.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to get the stylesheets and scripts first and append it to your `<head>` and then place the content.

Comment: could u please help me with the code. bad memory :(

Answer (score 0):

For the css files, you can find them using **[jQuery.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)** function, but the `<script>` will be stripped with this so instead we would have to use regex for the `<script>` tags.

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".form-control").change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'id=' + id;
            $("#loader_div").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_load_books.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {

                    //parsing <link>
                    var $str = $('<output>');
                    //loading html into fake tag
                    $str.load("ajax_load_books.php");
                    //now $str includes all your page code
                    temp = $.parseHTML(str);
                    $.each(temp, function (i, el) {
                       //finding the <link> tag
                       if (el.nodeName == 'LINK') {
                          //appending it to the <head> tag
                          $('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='" + el.getAttribute('href') + "'>");
                       }
                    });

                    //for script we will use regex
                    var pattern = /<script[^>]+?>.*?<\/script>/gi;
                    var matches = str.match(pattern);
                    var scripts = "";
                    for (var i in matches) {
                       scripts += matches[i];
                    }
                    //appending script tag to <head>
                    $('head').append(scripts);
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#loader_div").hide();
                    $("#txtHint").html(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/vavuquro/6/edit?js,output)**

There is a drawback with this, your stylesheets and script code will repeat. If the above code causes issue running because of the repetition, you should place the code of `beforeSend()` before the AJAX and have a parameter sent from your AJAX function indicating that when an AJAX is called with this parameter, to execute all the HTML except the stylesheets and js scripts.